# How to combine several vectors into one in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a scatter plot that i plotted in R using ggplot2. Graph was saved in pdf using ggsave(). For assembling figures for making a poster and/or publishing I prefer using Adobe Illustrator. Now when I open this graph in Illustrator, each gridline and data point is like a separate vector, it is fantastic to have graphs like this but it really kills my Mac down when I have to move few of these graphs around. Is there a way to merge or combine all these points into one vector.

Sorry if I have posted this in a wrong forum. Cheers!

Comment: Well I have found a workaround to the problem. It kind of does what I wanted to do but not sure if its the best solution.

In Mac Illustrator CS5 go to Object/Flattern Transparency.

Comment: You may get better performance if you edit in Outline mode too. Toggle using View>Outline/Preview or ctrl/cmd-Y. BTW Where can I find a plot generated by R to fiddle with?